# Updating in Mongoose thru Postman

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

In my mongoose controller, I have something like:

```
exports.update_a_task = function(req, res) {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.taskId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, task) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(task);
  });
};
```

And in my PUT command in Postman I put:

```
url/doSomething/taskId/name //or ,name
```

But it would only prompt a CastError. How should the URL look like if I want to update a document using the PUT command?

Comment: what does your req.body contain?

Comment: the only required in body is name, others are default.

Comment: you can specify name in query params as well

Comment: if you dont want to put name in query param remove &name=name from my ans

Comment: the url should look like this `url/doSomething/taskId`, so that in postman you can pass in the data you want to use to update the specified task.

Answer (score 0):

if taskId and name are query params then url becomes

```
url/doSomething/?taskId=123&name=name
```

Answer (score 0):

For this url: `url/doSomething/taskId`, you do something like this:

```
{
  name: "the_name_you_want"
}
```

Inside of Postman.

Answer (score 0):

To get it in mongoose you need to have the url like this
**url/doSomething/:taskId/:name**

then in postman you can do a put request to
**url/doSomething/taskId/name**
now you can use **req.params.taskId**

if you want to supply the data as **/url/doSomething?taskId=&name=** you would need to use 
**req.query.taskId**